# User Defined TabPage Loading into TabControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabpage

I am currently writing a small rolodex application for my own benefit and have come across a little problem.

I have a user defined TabPage dll that I wrote. The user enters information about a person on a blank UD-TabPage. Then I strip the information from the tabPage and store it in a `Record` Object that I created.

The user has the option to create many of these tabPages. And each time I store the info in a Record object and place that object in a `List<Record>`.

When the user is done entering contacts and wants to browse all of the tabs, I then place 26 tabPages on the TabControl, A-Z. And they will scroll to the tabPage that they want, so they can view their contact.

The problem I am running into is that I am unsure of how to take my data from the `List<record>` and put it back on the tabControl without having to create extra tabs. For example. If I have a person named "John Smith" and "Suzan Smith", I want to be able to scroll to the S tab and John's would be there first, and Suzan's would display when I hit next.

I have already alphabetized the tabs the user created. I am just unsure how to neatly display them.

If anybody has some ideas or some psuedocode that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: That sounds like a confusing and clumsy design to me.

Comment: I apologize. Thats why its a personal project of mine to attain more knowledge. Not for anything professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Dictionary). For example:

```
        List<record> cUngroupedRecords = new List<record>();

        Dictionary<string, List<record>> cGroupedRecords = new Dictionary<string, List<record>();

        foreach (record Record in cUngroupedRecords)
        {
            string sFirstChar = Record.LastName[0].ToString();
            List<record> cRecords;

            if (cGroupedRecords.ContainsKey(sFirstChar)) {
                cRecords = cGroupedRecords[sFirstChar];
            } else {
                cRecords = new List<string>();
                cGroupedRecords.Add(sFirstChar, cRecords);
            }
            cRecords.Add(Record);
        }
```

Then you can cycle through each group in cGroupedRecords.